# spring cloud stream kafka: : Error creating bean with name 'supplierInitializer' defined in class path resource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

> In the event you only have single bean of type java.util.function.[Supplier/Function/Consumer],  you can skip the spring.cloud.function.definition property, since such functional bean will be > > auto-discovered. However, it is considered best practice to use such property to avoid any
> confusion.

So I do have multiple beans in my project but still only one bean of type supplier.

Not sure what exactly what I am missing.

**EXCEPTION TRACE**:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'supplierInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/stream/function/FunctionConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userProducer-out-0_spca': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No poller has been defined for channel-adapter 'userProducer-out-0_spca', and no default poller is available within the context.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at com.moments.auth.AuthApplication.main(AuthApplication.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userProducer-out-0_spca': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No poller has been defined for channel-adapter 'userProducer-out-0_spca', and no default poller is available within the context.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.integration.dsl.context.IntegrationFlowBeanPostProcessor.registerComponent(IntegrationFlowBeanPostProcessor.java:456) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.5.jar:5.5.5]
    at org.springframework.integration.dsl.context.IntegrationFlowBeanPostProcessor.processStandardIntegrationFlow(IntegrationFlowBeanPostProcessor.java:234) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.5.jar:5.5.5]
    at org.springframework.integration.dsl.context.IntegrationFlowBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(IntegrationFlowBeanPostProcessor.java:116) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.5.jar:5.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$1.afterPropertiesSet(FunctionConfiguration.java:241) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No poller has been defined for channel-adapter 'userProducer-out-0_spca', and no default poller is available within the context.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:219) ~[spring-core-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean.initializeAdapter(SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean.java:181) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.5.jar:5.5.5]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean.java:144) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.5.jar:5.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
```

**POM.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.moments</groupId>
    <artifactId>auth</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>auth</name>
    <description>Auth service</description>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>-->
<!--            <scope>test</scope>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>16</source>
                    <target>16</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Starter code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AuthApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AuthApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Bean
    public Supplier<String> userProducer() {
        return () -> "hello";
    }
}
```

**YML File**

```
spring:
  cloud.stream:
    function.definition : userProducer

    bindings:
      userProducer-out-0:
        destination: users # topic

    kafka.binder:
      brokers: localhost
      configuration:
        key:
          serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      defaultBrokerPort: 9002
```

Comment: Consider posting a complete example that reproduces the issue to Github and leaving a link here, this way we can take a look what's wrong with your app

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky done, please take a look https://github.com/karunvarma/auth-service

Comment: See also my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `<spring-cloud.version>2021.0.0</spring-cloud.version>` you have to use:

```
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
```

The `poller` configuration has been removed from Spring Cloud Stream `3.2.x` in favor of respective auto-configuration in Spring Boot: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#messaging.spring-integration

Comment: thank you. but the documentation you pointed out,does not mention removing the poller-configuration. could you point out exactly where can I find such information.

Comment: Well, Spring Boot has just added a new feature. It didn't remove anything. So, anything to mention in that Spring Boot about removal. Spring Cloud Stream, on the other hand, indeed did remove that configuration. See docs here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.2.1/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_polling_configuration_properties - `although deprecated since version 3.2`